# Looking for correct/appropriate word which represents, it's not SLA Missed because the defined SLA time is not over

Tags: word-choice

I am just trying to find the correct word for a particular scenario.

Three types of Service-Level-Agreement/SLA are available

1. SLA (Service-Level-Agreement)Meet
2. SLA (Service-Level-Agreement) Missed
3. Not SLA Missed because the defined SLA time is not over

I am looking for specific word for option 3. What should be the correct/appropriate word which represents, it's not SLA Missed because the defined SLA time is not over.

Comment: We are *still within the parameters* of the SLA. We have not *exceeded the parameters* of the SLA.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking back, in retrospect, at whether a Service Level Agreement has been met or not met, you would use the past partciple:

**met** (not "meet").
**missed** or **not met**

If the SLA term has not yet run to completion, then it cannot have been **met** but it can have been **missed**.

If it has not yet been **missed**, you could use the word **pending**.

Comment: Or "in progress".

Comment: Or even "N/A" for *not applicable* or *not available*, since you can't yet state whether the SLA was met or not.